# Is there an attribute that adds the correct response type attribute for each function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an API and I am facing a simple problem, I have to add `[ProducesResponseType("return status code (int) here")]` on top of each function for each return type to produce better documentation.

The problem is that the code will be hard to maintain, because each change may or may not have another change following it.

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromBody] Product product)
{
    if (product.Description.Contains("XYZ Widget"))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    await _repository.AddProductAsync(product);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = product.Id }, product);
}
```

is there a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Make what dynamic? Also, can you post your code of the `CreatedAtAction` Method? Plus, shouldn't the parameter of the `CreatedActAction` method be `nameof(CreateAsync)` instead of `nameof(GetById)`

Comment: If you want to support this, you'd have to create a custom attribute that inspects your code and enlists all possible return types. In order for that to work correctly, you'd first have to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), i.e. it's hard.

Comment: @MindSwipe the OP means that when they add `if (foo) { return NotFound(); }`, they manually have to add `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]`, and they want the latter to happen automatically.

Comment: @CodeCaster if determining the type is a problem, would the status code create the same problem as well ?

Comment: @MindSwipe the code is taken from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @Hoshani yeah what if you add a method to your controller that returns a custom status code? So in your action method you have `if (bar) { return GenerateStatusCode(200 + 5); }`, and in `GenerateStatusCode(int code)` you do `return new HttpStatusCodeResultDerivedClass(code)`? Your attribute will have to analyze and follow that code all the way down, and extract the status code used. And what if `200 + 5` isn't hardcoded, but comes from a database, or worse, from user input?

Comment: Best to just boil this down as *no*. You need to manually add the `ProducesResponseType` attribute for each potential response type.